# 2-D matrices using malloc failing to assign correct values

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

sorry, I'm relatively new to c and am trying to create two 2-D arrays using malloc. I was told that this method is computationally more efficient than creating a pointer array of arrays through a for loop (for large arrays).

```
int i, j;
double **PNow, **PNext, *Array2D1, *Array2D2;

//Allocate memory
PNow = (double**)malloc(3 * sizeof(double*));
PNext = (double**)malloc(3 * sizeof(double*));
Array2D1 = (double*)malloc(5 * sizeof(double));
Array2D2 = (double*)malloc(5 * sizeof(double));

//Create 2-Dimensionality
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    PNow[i] = Array2D1 + i * 5;
    PNext[i] = Array2D2 + i * 5;
};


//Define Element Values
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        PNow[i][j] = 10.*(i + j);
        PNext[i][j] = 1000.*(i + j);
    };
};


//Output two matrices side-by-side.
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {

        printf("%6lg", PNow[i][j]);
        if(j == 4)
        {
            printf("|");
        };
    };
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {

        printf("%6lg", PNext[i][j]);
        if(j == 4)
        {
            printf("\n");
        };
    };
};
```

My problem is that the first matrix (PNow) turns out as I would expect, but for some reason half of the values in PNext are those of PNow, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it is doing this? I'm obviously missing something.. Also I am not overly clear on what "Array2D1 + i*5" is doing and how this makes PNow a 2-D array?

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

P.S. This is the output that I am getting, so you can see what I mean:

```
 0    10    20    30    40|    20    30    40    50    20
10    20    30    40    50|    30    40    50    60  5000
20    30    40    50    60|  2000  3000  4000  5000  6000
```

Comment: Have you got [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) available?  If so, use it.  A casual look at the code suggests you are not allocating enough memory (for `Array2D1` and `Array2D2` in particular), and are therefore writing out of bounds.

Comment: You should get out of the habit of putting semicolons after `}` — it would be wrong if you had an `else` clause following and isn't necessary most of the rest of the time.  The semicolon is necessary after the `}` at the end of a type definition (eg a `struct` or `union`), or after an initializer.  It is not necessary or desirable after a compound statement.

Comment: There is no 2D array (aka matrix) in your code and nothing which can point to one. A pointer is not an array! And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't realise that a `;` shouldn't be placed after `}`, thank you! Also @Olaf I'm curious as to how this differs from a 2D array as the usage seems to be the same. `PNow[i][j]` works as you would expect for a 2D array? As I said in the post, I am unsure exactly what `PNow[i] = Array2D1 + i*5` is doing?

Comment: @TBK12 So PNow is actually an array of pointers, and Array2D1 is a pointer. Therefore, `Array2D1 + i*5` is saying is "give me the pointer to the memory that is `i*5` doubles away from the pointer `Array2D1`. When you increment a pointer, you increment by the size of what it's pointing to. So, it's filling PNow with pointers to appropriately sized memory chunks for the rows.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I didn't realise that's what it was doing :)

Comment: @TBK12: The `r * cols + c` formula is actually what would be used to index a 2D array, so it simulates 2D addressing in a 1D array. You could easily use that already to process the matrices, no need for the additional array of pointers (and some older matrix libs actually do). Problem is that formula is not very intuitive to use and error-prone. Thus the additional pointer. See my answer (again) to find the correct way for a 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you don't cast the result of mallocs, so your malloc lines should read

```
PNow = malloc(3*sizeof(double*));
```

Your problem is you're not actually allocating enough memory in `Array2D1` and `Array2D2`. When you move past the first "row" in your array you're getting beyond your allocated memory! So you're in undefined behavior territory. In your case, it looks like your two matrices step all over each other (though my test just throws an error). You can solve this in two ways:

Specify the full size of your matrix in the malloc and do as you did:

```
Array2D1 = malloc(15*sizeof(double));
Array2D2 = malloc(15*sizeof(double));
```

Or malloc each line in your for loop:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    PNow[i] = malloc(5*sizeof(double));
    PNext[i] = malloc(5*sizeof(double));
}
```

Edit: On the topic of freeing in each example

For the first example, the freeing is straight forward

```
free(PNow);
free(PNext);
free(Array2D1);
free(Array2D2);
```

For the second, you must iterate through each line and free individually

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    free(PNow[i]);
    free(PNext[i]);
}
```

Edit2: Realistically, if you're going to hardcode your rows and columns in with a pre-processor macro, there's no reason to malloc at all. You can simply do this:

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 5

double PNow[ROW][COL], PNext[ROW][COL];
```

Edit3: As for what `Array2D1 + i * 5` is doing, `PNow` is an array of pointers, and `Array2D1` is a pointer. By adding `i * 5` you're incrementing the pointer by `i * 5` (i.e., saying "give me a pointer to the memory that is `i * 5` doubles away from `Array2D1`). So, you're filling `PNow` with pointers to the starts of appropriately sized memory chunks for your rows.

Comment: @GeorgiaStuart I can't believe I missed that! Changing it to your first answer fixed it, thank you! I know about the for loop method (it's the one I would personally use), but I was told not to use it due to it being "less efficient".

Comment: No problem. Also, as @olaf says, put your columns and rows in a `#define` at the top of your code if you're going to hard code it in :).

Comment: Thank you, it's actually something that will be input by the user, I just hard coded for the sake of the example :)

Answer (score 0):

You code does not have 2D arrays, aka matrices. And your pointers cannot point to such an object either.

A proper pointer which can point to a 2D array would be declared like:

```
#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 5

double (*arr)[COLS];
```

Allocation is straight-forward:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * ROWS);
```

And deleting similar:

```
free(arr);
```

Indexing is like:

```
arr[row][col]
```

Notice the identical **syntax** only. The semantics are different.

Nothing more necessary and no need for hand-crafted pointer arrays.

The code above shows another important rule: Don't use magic values. Use constant-like macros instead. These should be `#defined` at the beginning or in a configuration-section of the code (typically somewhere near the top of the file or a distinct header file). So if you lateron change e.g. the length of a dimension, you don't have to edit all places you explicitly wrote it, but only change the macro once.

While the code above uses constants, you can as well use variables for the dimensions. This is standard C and called variable length array (VLA). If you pass the arrays to other functions, you have to pass them as additional arguments:

```
void f(size_t rows, size_t cols, double a[rows][cols]);
```

Remember array-arguments decay to pointers to the first element, so `a` is actually the same as `arr` above. The outermost dimension can be omitted, but as you need it anyway it is good for documentation to specify it, too.

Comment: If we're assuming the values are hardcoded in, there's no reason to malloc at all. We can simply do `PNow[ROW][COL]`.

Comment: You have a valid point about defining the number of rows and columns at the start of the file. However, as I said in another comment, the intent is that they are dependent on input by the user. I do, however, like your set up, such that if one of the dimensions are known (e.g. columns) then you can set up a 2D array much easier than using a for loop. Unfortunately though, that isn't possible for the problem at hand...

Comment: @GeorgiaStuart: Try allocation any matrix larger than few MiB on the stack or return such a local variable from a function. Also that's what OP apparently wants. Not sure what you mean with hard-coded. See the edit, you can use a VLA (for either variant), too.

Comment: @Olaf You can only count on VLAs if you use C99. As of C11 they're optional for implementation. C90 and earlier forbids it. Also, I use a similar allocation scheme in my research for "matrices" that are >100 MB, routinely.

Comment: @GeorgiaStuart: 1) C standard is C11. C90 is not standard -> irrelevant without a specific tag. 2) Every modern compiler supporting C11 also supports C99. 3) If it supports C99, it also supports VLAs in C11. Using a pre-C99 compiler is a bad idea anyway, as some semantics have changed incompatibility with C99, while C11 mostly added some extension. 4) Making a previously mandatory feature of the core language optional in C11 was a really bad idea and likely due to some outdated commercial compilers who cannot maintain their tools properly. 5) It is a valid and correct answer. No reason for DV.